# Plugin scheduled event not working

Tags: plugins, options, cron

I have created this interval in my functions.php:

```
function minute_interval( $schedules ) {
  $schedules['minute'] = array(
    'interval' => 60,
    'display' => __('Every minute')
  );
  return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'minute_interval' );
```

I have this scheduled event in my plugin:

```
if (! wp_next_scheduled ( 'my_event' )) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'minute', 'my_event');
}

add_action( 'my_event', 'my_function' );
function my_function() {
    update_option('test_option', 'test_value');
}
```

The event is added to the scheduled events list. However, it seems not to start my_function() as Wordpress does not create or update "test_option".

Others scheduled events from Wordpress are working well.

Any idea how I could make my event work?

Edit: after installing WP control, here's what is displayed :

[image]

edit2: my wp_schedule_event() and my_function() are both in the initialization function of my plugin, which is started when my plugin is activated.

Comment: to debug that, try a plugin like `WP Crontrol` to look if your event is realy scheduled.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add filter:

```
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'minute_interval' );
```

Otherwise your function  minute_interval is not invoked, interval is not defined, and event doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I do have this line, I just forgot to copy paste it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to move my_function() outside my plugin init function.